# Is a 1954 patent still worth anything?

Tags: term, us2694522

I recently came across a patent of my Uncle's from 1954, and I'm wondering whether it could be worth anything today.

I believe it has to do with time navigation in the ocean.

How can I find out whether it's worth anything? The patent number is US2694522.

Answer (score 1):

A patent is valid for 20 years (17 then) today assuming renewal fees are paid

Now this patent may be worth something in a nice frame

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an expired patent it has *no value*. In 1956 patents had a term of 17 years from the date of *grant*, and maintenance fees did not exist in the US until 1980 or so. Today patents terminate 20 years after the day of the application *filing*. If a patent took 3 years before being granted, it would end up being in-force for 17 years.